# Percentage change in monthly sales from average sales of a time period

Tags: formula, average, finance

I want to know what is this method called and if it's a standard way of calculating change in monthly sales from average sales.

[image]

For Example, calculating % change in sales of month '6/22' from average sales:
Average = (16243 + 1500 + 0 + 0 + 3216 + 13216) / 6 = 34175 / 6 = 5696

% change in '6/22' = ((16243-5696)/5696)*100 = 185% Increase

Answer (score 0):

(New - old) / old * 100% is called [percentage change](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/percentage-change.html)

Comment: But in my scenario, 'old' is mean/average of sales of all months and 'new' is sales of any month

Comment: @AdilAhmed in that case, you don't want percentage change but just 'percentage of'

In which case you have to use the formula (input / compareTo) * 100, so in your case it would be 16242 / 5696 * 100 = 285,14% increase

See https://www.embibe.com/exams/how-to-calculate-percentage/

If you want to know how much it has changed, use the one in my answer. If you want to know how much it is compared to another, use the formula in my comment.